# partial differentiation - maximum point - $3 $ variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative, maxima-minima

I'm asked to maximise the volume of a rectangular cuboid inscribed in the ellipsoid

$4x^2 + 4y^2 + 9z^2 = 36$

and i'm given a hint that the rectangular cuboid has volume $8xyz$

### .

How do I go about finding the maximum for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Try to use [Lagrange Multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)

Comment: In the question I'm also told that g(x,y,z) = 0. So now that I have 3 equations formed, how do I use this information that g(x,y,z) = 0?

Comment: What function is g(x,y,z)?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you mean by that. It's the constraint.

Comment: $v(x,y,z)=8xyz$ and $f(x,y,z)=4x^2+4y^2+9z^2-36$

Comment: Oh so all it's telling me is that I can make: f(x,y,z) = 4x^2+4y^2+9z^2 - 36?

Comment: $\nabla$ $v(x,y,z)=(8yz,8zx,8xy) and $\nabla$ $f(x,y,z)=(8x,8y,18z).
You should use $f(x,y,z)=4x^2+4y^2+9z^2-36$ as an equation of the system

Comment: Yes, that is the restriction

Comment: $2x=2y=3z$.  So $4y^2+4y^2+4y^2=36$,$4x^2+4x^2+4x^2=36$,$9z^2+9z^2+9z^2=36$

Comment: I got 16x^2 + 16x^2 + 36x^2 = 36 when I substituted 2x into the equation. But I see that you didn't do this. Why haven't you multiplied by the coefficients (4, 4 and 9)?

Comment: $2x=2y$ so $4x^2=4y^2$

Comment: $(sqrt(3),sqrt(3),\frac{2sqrt(3)}{3})$

Comment: Now that I have that 2x = 2y = 3z = +- 2√3 do I find the maxima by substituting this into 8xyz? or do I put the individual values of x = √3, y = √3, and z = √4/3 into 8xyz?

Comment: just put the individual values

Comment: thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Apply Arithmetic Mean - Geometric Mean inequality we have: $
36 = 4x^2+4y^2+9z^2 \ge 3\sqrt[3]{144(xyz)^2}$. From this you can conclude. Observe that the max occurs at $2x = 2y = 3z$.